# Maximum size of .NET arrays

Tags: .net, arrays

Not that I would ever need to do this, but I want to understand how it works/doesn't work. I googled quite a bit for the maximum length of an array and can't really find anything.

```
long[] hugeArray = new long[long.MaxValue];

//No exceptions
Console.WriteLine("Init");

//Overflow exception
Console.WriteLine(hugeArray.LongLength.ToString());

hugeArray = new long[int.MaxValue];

//OutOfMemoryException
Console.WriteLine( hugeArray.Length.ToString());
```

And I guess a follow up question would be, if there is a limit and I am initializing outside that limit, why no exception when creating only when using? And is this something the compiler should catch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum length of an array in .NET on 64-bit Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [SpankyJ](http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx), .NET 2.0 at least had a limit of 2 GB per array.  8 bytes (sizeof long) * ~2^31 = 16 gigabytes (not to mention the actual memory required).  As for the Overflow, I agree with marcc that is probably because arrays are expected to be int-indexed (see e.g. [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx)  Though I'm a bit uncertain regarding this, as [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8w3at5.aspx) takes an array of Int64 lengths.  This may be an extension only available in later versions.

Overall, though, this is mostly a theoretical issue.  Anyone actually relying on this is likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The underlying IL opcodes for arrays deal with `IntPtr` (known as **native int** in the IL documentation):

- `newarr` creates an array, and accepts an `IntPtr`
- `ldelem` and `stelem` read and write elements, and they use an `IntPtr` index
- `ldlen` returns the length of an array, and it returns an unsigned `IntPtr`

I'd expect a theoretical limit on the number of elements of 2^31-1 on 32-bit platforms, and 2^63-1 on 64-bit platforms.

However, I just tried this code on my 64-bit PC, and I got an `OutOfMemoryException` on the first allocation, so clearly the practical limits are smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The index of an array is an int, not long.  So, I guess technically new long[int.MaxValue] would be the maximum.  But you could still get the OutOfMemoryException you are seeing if you really do run out of memory.  Are you running this on a 32-bit OS?  There isn't a set maximum length, other than the index value is an int, not a long.