# Array Length/LongLength in .NET

Tags: c#, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum length of an array in .NET on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows)

What is the exact maximum *theoretical* size of an array on a x86 platform in .NET? Is is given by `Int32.MaxValue` or `UInt32.MaxValue`?

Comment: I would say an indirect duplicate at best, the question itself certainly gives you the impression they are not duplicated, but the eventual answer seems the same.

Comment: Again that is a theoretical limit, as the address space itself is bounded by 2GB limit on 32 bit Windows, therefore no program would be allowed to reach that limint in CLR.

Answer (score 3):

In theory it's 2,147,483,647 item (ie 2GB) at it uses an int. However, given that an array is a contiguous block of memory of memory and a process can only have 2GB of userspace you'll never actually be able to populate an array of this size as your userspace will have code and other app data in it which will reduce space available.

Comment: On 64 bits the limit is not on the process, but on the .net (that limits the objects to 2gb) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is determined by the value of **Int32.MaxValue**