# why does c# List implementation specify this exact value in the ensure capacity method?

Tags: c#, list

using ILspy the code is :

```
private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
{
if (this._items.Length < min)
{
    int num = (this._items.Length == 0) ? 4 : (this._items.Length * 2);
    if (num > 2146435071)
    {
        num = 2146435071;
    }
    if (num < min)
    {
        num = min;
    }
    this.Capacity = num;
}
}
```

why is it checking if the num is greater than 2146435071 specifically shouldn't it just check for underflow & set num=Int.Max or anyother value greater than min?

Comment: Note that if `_items.Length * 2` overflows (and the result becomes negative), `num` will later be changed to `min` because of the last `if`. It does seem a little strange that exceeding `0x7fefffff` without overflowing leads to another result than exceeding `0x7fffffff`, i.e. overflowing.

Comment: Well in the first if-statement `num` is casted to `uint` which ensures correct overflow checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is connected to a fact, that `List<T>` uses array as internal storage, and maximum array size is set to `2146435071`.

Read [What is the maximum length of an array in .NET on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows) about array max size.

You can easily create your own `IList<T>` implementation which will not use array as internal storage, and will allow more than `2146435071` elements. Of course, you're still limited by `int.MaxValue` as max number of elements, because `IList<T>.Count` returns `int`.

Comment: That link also mentions that `2146435071` is `0x7fefffff` and yes, it seems the value was chosen to make sure the backing array can support it.