# Is there any limitation of size in ILArray? (ILNumerics)

Tags: arrays, matrix, overflow, ilnumerics

I try to made a large matrix using ILArray.

```
ILArray<double> distanceAll = ILMath.zeros(111561, 111561);
```

But it produce error. It said "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."
So, is there a limitation of the size in ILArray? Is it because I use the community edition?

I want to buy the business version. But I need to evaluate this first. I am afraid if it will be the same with the business edition. Because we have a large of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array you are trying to create would take up 93GB of memory. Handling such arrays as a whole is (still) not feasible (today). I suggest you split up your data in some way.

As a rule of thumb you can handle arrays up to a quarter of the available RAM on you machine efficiently. However there is still a systematic limit introduced by .NET: [What is the maximum length of an array in .NET on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows)