# Can't create huge arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Like many other programmers, I went into [primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), and as many of them, what I like is the challenge, so I'm not looking for comment like *Atkin did this faster than you dude*, but just a solution - or at least an hint - to my issue.

I need to create **big** arrays (like size > `int.MaxValue`). So I went to a lot of web pages and found the [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) one. I thought I was saved, add the following magic to my `App.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But it *didn't* work. Here's the code I use :

```
void go(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    t.Stop();
    ulong maxprime = 10;
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    string s = String.Empty;
    while (maxprime < ulong.MaxValue)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
        richTextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + ("Max \t= " + maxprime.ToString("N0"));
        try
        {
            richTextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + ("Count \t= " + GetAllPrimesLessThan(maxprime).Count);
            richTextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + ("Time \t= " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
            richTextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + ("--------------------------------");
            maxprime *= 10;
            richTextBox2.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            s = exception.Message + "; Allocation size: " + (maxprime + 1).ToString("N0");
            break;
        }
        
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        richTextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + s;
    }
    richTextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + ("Done.");
}

private static List<ulong> GetAllPrimesLessThan(ulong maxPrime)
{
    var primes = new List<ulong>() { 2 };
    var maxSquareRoot = Math.Sqrt(maxPrime);
    var eliminated = new bool[maxPrime + 1];

    for (ulong i = 3; i <= maxPrime; i += 2)
    {
        if (!eliminated[i])
        {
            primes.Add(i);
            if (i < maxSquareRoot)
            {
                for (ulong j = i * i; j <= maxPrime; j += 2 * i)
                {
                    eliminated[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Which output this:

```
[...]
Max     = 1 000 000 000
Count   = 50847534
Time    = 00:00:15.3355367
--------------------------------
Max     = 10 000 000 000
Array dimensions exceeded supported range.; Allocation size: 10 000 000 001
Done.
```

How can I get rid of this error?

---

FYI: I've got

- 16GB ram;
- 32GB memory mapped(/paged?) on SSD;
- 64bits enabled

Comment: If you want to avoid creating huge arrays, you should consider partitioning. You can find a subtle reference in the [NIST FIPS spec](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf). Page 80 (which is 90 if viewing in Chrome). You still cannot exceed `2,147,483,647` elements, but you can get near that many primes.

Comment: Check this out have a similar discussion and explanation, it refers to using BigArray<T> to go beyond 2 GB limit
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0

Comment: Dude... Wrong bull. I know that now an then, large arrays are required, but you should use partitioning or other technique to NOT RUN OUT OF MEMORY.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From your link:

> Using this element in your application configuration file enables arrays that are **larger than 2 GB in size**, but does not change other limits on object size or array size:
>
> The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.

See also [What is the maximum length of an array in .NET on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows):

> An array could theoretically have at most 2,147,483,647 elements, **since it uses an int for indexing**.

Answer (score 10):

If you hit the bounds of the integer max range, you can opt to use a `long`-index-based array.

The problem is that this isn't supported by the [C# indexer properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), which uses `int`. You can build them by hand though by using [`Array.CreateInstance(Type, long[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8w3at5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note you have to get the values using [`Array.GetValue(long)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zexc3z9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), Int32.MaxValue)` throws `OutOfMemoryException` on 64 bit, `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), UInt32.MaxValue)` throws _"Arrays larger than 2GB are not supported"_ even with the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` setting enabled... (.NET 4.5.3).