# Create huge dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

In my quest to the primes, I've already asked this question : [Can't create huge arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30895549/2307070%20Can't%20create%20huge%20arrays) which lead me to create my own class of fake arrays based on a dictionary of arrays... : `private Dictionary<int, Array> arrays = new Dictionary<int, Array>();`

I can know create fake arrays of a lot of bool (like `10 000 000 000`) using the code below:

```
public class CustomArray
{
    private Dictionary<int, Array> arrays = new Dictionary<int, Array>();

    public CustomArray(ulong lenght)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (lenght > 0x7FFFFFC7)
        {
            lenght -= 0x7FFFFFC7;
            arrays[i] = new bool[0x7FFFFFC7];
            i++;
        }
        arrays[i] = new bool[lenght];
    }
}
```

But it crashes as soon as I ask for a CustomArray of `100 000 000 000` elements. It works well for the 25 first iterations (my Dictionary contains 25 arrays of 0x7FFFFFC7 elements) but then it crashes with an `OutOfMemory` exception.

<sub>As a remainder, I've got 16GB memory, VS2013, the program is compiled in 64bits, I've enabled the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` option and I don't see any memory peak in the Task Manager.</sub>

---

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Why dictionaries out of all things? Wouldn't a jagged array be more appropriate?

Comment: @Luaan random choice, I was in the mood for dictionary...

Comment: also bool is not an efficient type for storing information. You could simply store 64 bools in a ulong (8 bytes) rather than a 64 bool array (64 bytes)

Comment: Well, you *don't* have enough memory for `100 000 000 000` `bool`s, not even by far. Each `bool` takes a byte, so your 16 GiB will run out with just 16 billion items. You don't see a spike because the *physical* memory doesn't necessarily get allocated (it's all zeroes, so it's mapped to zero-page), but that's just a hidden optimization. C# `bool` isn't a single bit. 25 arrays of 0x7FFFFFC7 elements takes *50 GiB*!

Comment: @Luaan sizeof(bool) returns 1

Comment: why do you need to store all those prime numbers in memory?

Comment: @Andrey I'm using this [kind of code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C.23)

Comment: @Thomas it is not suitable method for generation of large amount of primes

Comment: @Andrey well, if you have any recommendation, I'll be glad to take a look to it !

Comment: @Thomas https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Efficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042902/most-elegant-way-to-generate-prime-numbers

Comment: @Andrey well I'm confused. I use a Sieve and both of your links points to a Sieve... Did I miss something?

Comment: @Thomas you are right, I thought I was there something more efficient. Well, if you want to use sieve for such large numbers you need to implement pagination and store unused pages on disk.

Comment: @Andrey yup, that's going to be fun :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

100000000000 bools means ~93 GB of memory. You only have @50 GB (including the default allocated virtual memory).

Storing them as bits (not as bytes), would get you down to ~12GB.

Look at [System.Collection.BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx)