# Concurrent collection with constant read time

Tags: c#

`ConcurrentDictionary` offer constant read time. I do not need key-value pairs, only keys.. I searched for read times on `ConcurrentBag` and havent found how it is implemented?

Is there a constant read time ConcurrentCollection, besides ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: Also look at [immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=netcore-3.1) collections. E.g. `ImmutableHashSet`

Answer (score 1):

[ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netcore-3.1) is probably not what you are looking for:

> Represents a thread-safe, unordered collection of objects.

Which means that it allows duplicates (whereas the dictionary doesn't)

> Bags are useful for storing objects when ordering doesn't matter, and unlike sets, bags support duplicates.

As for performance, it certainly isn't as much performant as a list (so at least `O(n)`) ([C# - Performance comparison of ConcurrentBag vs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416565/c-sharp-performance-comparison-of-concurrentbag-vs-list))

For a `ConcurrentSet` check your luck with the custom implementation here: [How to implement ConcurrentHashSet in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306936/how-to-implement-concurrenthashset-in-net)

You can also check the [list of Concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netcore-3.1) to see if something else suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with ConcurrentCollection.

Comment: Glad I could help