# Does the .net framework provides async methods for working with the file-system?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, filesystems, async-await, system.io.file

Does the .net framework has an `async` built-in library/assembly which allows to work with the file system (e.g. `File.ReadAllBytes`, `File.WriteAllBytes`)?

Or do I have to write my own library using the `async` Methods of `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`?

Something like this would be pretty nice:

```
var bytes = await File.ReadAllBytes("my-file.whatever");
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Does the .net framework has an async built-in library/assembly which allows to work with the file system

Yes. There are async methods for working with the file system but not for the helper methods on the static `File` type. They are on `FileStream`.

So, there's no `File.ReadAllBytesAsync` but there's `FileStream.ReadAsync`, etc. For example:

```
byte[] result;
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@"C:\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    result = new byte[stream.Length];
    await stream.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)stream.Length);
}
```

Comment: If the file you were serializing into a byte stream was large (3gb+) is there a possibilty that the stream length would infact be larger than an int type can store and casue it to overflow?

Comment: @Dave probably. In such cases you probably need to read in chunks.

Comment: You should have logic to read in chunks regardless. According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.readasync?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_FileStream_ReadAsync_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Threading_CancellationToken_), ReadAsync is not guaranteed to fill the whole array. You need to check the return value to see how much it _actually_ read.

Comment: You may consider changing the code to [something like this](https://pastebin.com/68PrKYJg) (for small files - don't do it like this for 3 GB+ files).

Comment: You should really be using `System.IO.StreamReader` to read instead of grabbing raw bytes. It has `ReadLineAsync` and `ReadToEndAsync` methods.

Comment: There is a race which risks overflow if the file size increases. I suggest reading b.Length bytes in the last line.  Also, from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows  .NET objects have a limit of 2GB, so you can't read more than that at a time. This helps as b.Length < 2^21 .

Answer (score 21):

It already does it. See for example [Using Async for File Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx) MSDN article.

```
private async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> Does the .net framework has an async built-in library/assembly which allows to work with the file system (e.g. File.ReadAllBytes, File.WriteAllBytes)?

Unfortunately, the desktop APIs are a bit spotty when it comes to asynchronous file operations. As you noted, a number of the nice convenience methods do not have asynchronous equivalents. Also missing are asynchronous *opening* of files (which is especially useful when opening files over a network share).

I'm hoping these APIs will be added as the world moves to .NET Core.

> Or do I have to write my own library using the async Methods of StreamReader and StreamWriter?

That's the best approach right now.

Note that when using `ReadAsync`/`WriteAsync` and friends, you must *explicitly* open the file for asynchronous access. The only way to do this (currently) is to use a `FileStream` constructor overload that takes a `bool isAsync` parameter (passing `true`) or a `FileOptions` parameter (passing `FileOptions.Asynchronous`). So you can't use the convenience open methods like `File.Open`.

Comment: Thanks for that information and especially: `FileOptions.Asynchronous` thank you! `isAsync` seems to be depricated. +1

Comment: @BendEg If you saw the deprecation warning near a bunch of [constructor overloads for `FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2), those obsoletes appear to be for the `IntPtr` variations of `FileStream()` due to the better/safer `SafeHandle` alternative. You can see that, for example, [this filename overload with `useAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7db28s3c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is not marked obsoleted.

Answer (score 7):

In .NET core (since version 2.0) there are now all the async flavors of corresponding ReadAll/WriteAll/AppendAll methods like:

```
File.(Read|Write|Append)All(Text|Lines|Bytes)Async
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytesasync?view=netcore-2.1

Unfortunately, they are still missing from .NET standard 2.0.

Comment: It's now available in .net standard 2.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytesasync?view=netstandard-2.1

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the `FileStream` to create the same behavior.

Here are the helper methods I've created for a `NetStandart 2.0 class library`, that was used both in `NetCore 3.1` and `NetFramework 4.7.2` projects.

These implementations have matched exactly the names and signatures of the net core 3.1 / net standard 2.1 `File` class methods, so you only need to put them in any public class. (FileHelper for example...):

Also, this should be most efficient and similar to the source code of .net implementation.

```
private const int DefaultBufferSize = 4096;

    // File accessed asynchronous reading and sequentially from beginning to end.
    private const FileOptions DefaultOptions = FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan;

    public static async Task WriteAllTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
    {
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        using FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
            DefaultBufferSize, true);
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ReadAllLinesAsync(string filePath)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();

        using var sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
            DefaultBufferSize, DefaultOptions);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream, Encoding.Unicode);
        string line;
        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null) lines.Add(line);

        return lines;
    }

    public static async Task<string> ReadAllTextAsync(string filePath)
    {
        using var sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
            DefaultBufferSize, DefaultOptions);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream, Encoding.Unicode);
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer from the future :)...

Now you can invoke `File.ReadAllBytesAsync()` directly without using streams starting with .Net Core 2.0.

**Definition:**

```
public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> ReadAllBytesAsync (string path, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

**Returns:**

```
Task<Byte[]>
```

> A task that represents the asynchronous read operation, which wraps
> the byte array containing the contents of the file.

**Applies to:**

> .NET Core 2.0, Core 2.1, Core 2.2, Core 3.0, Core 3.1, 5, 6, 7 Preview
> 7

This new API is [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytesasync?view=net-6.0)