# Threads in Unity to avoid Animation freeze

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, thread-safety, threadpool

Every time I load a texture from a saved file, any animation in my scene is frozen until the loading from file is done.
I read so many different opinions about Threads, and none got answers. but I have to load the texture in a different thread to avoid freezing. 
My code is attached to a gameobject which is a UI popup window

```
void Start() {
Texture2D tex = LoadTexFromFile(); //Should be in a diffrent thread that returns a texture
sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, 
                       new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), 
                       new Vector2(tex.width / 2, tex.height / 2));

picFrame.GetComponent<Image>().overrideSprite = sprite; }
```

How do I safely use threads in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Unity - Load a file on background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234452/android-unity-load-a-file-on-background-thread)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Also, that user didn't get answers.

Comment: I was thinking then why @Michał Powłoka ticked that answer then ?

Comment: He answered his own question with a workaround because people didn't answer him. Also, the way he reads file is different than my code, I don't have access to LoadTexFromFile() and he found a workaround on the reader itself which I don't have access to

Answer (score 0):

[Best practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135) say that you should **not** load assets during a level but rather at the **start** so as to avoid disruption.  Why are you going against what middleware like Unity provides?  Let it manage your assests for you and load them at the start of the level.

There is a use-case (**not** specific for Unity) for *asset streaming* but is generally reserved for AAA on-demand asset loading such as textures; mesh; and other assets in say large *open-world games* but I doubt this is the case here.  Such a feature is highly complicated and I won't go into it here.

### Tell me more

- Gregory, J, *[Game Engine Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135)*, 2009

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't load everything at the start, because it's a lot of tex screenshot to load on the memory for nothing. My scene is a map, and every level stores a screenshot texture. When clicking on a level, a saved texture should be loaded from a file. If I start loading all the screenshots from all levels at the start it'll take a long time for the scene to start, which is the case already. That's why I want to separate the loading texture on a different thread

Comment: @SHAI sounds to me that your game assets are not optimsed _per level_.  Unity is there to do this sort of thing for you.  If you find this isn't the case then there is something wrong