# Array.Copy --> Arrays larger than 2GB are not supported

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, .net-4.5, gcallowverylargeobjects

I'm using the [Array.Copy Method (Array, Array, Int64)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btfeahds(v=vs.110).aspx). I've the following static method

```
public static T[,] Copy<T>(T[,] a)
    where T : new()
{
    long n1 = a.GetLongLength(0);
    long n2 = a.GetLongLength(1);
    T[,] b = new T[n1, n2];
    System.Array.Copy(a, b, n1 * n2);
    return b;
}
```

and the following code to test it

```
double[,] m1 = new double[46340, 46340];
double[,] m2 = Copy(m1); // works

double[,] m3 = new double[46341, 46341];
double[,] m4 = Copy(m3); // Arrays larger than 2GB are not supported
                         // length argument of Array.Copy
```

I'm aware of `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />` and I've set it to true.

I saw in the documentation of [Array.Copy Method (Array, Array, Int64)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btfeahds(v=vs.110).aspx) that there is the following remark for the length argument.

> A 64-bit integer that represents the number of elements to copy. The integer must be between zero and [Int32.MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), inclusive.

I cannot understand why there is this limit for the length argument when the type is `Int64`? Is there a workaround? Is it planned to remove this limit in an upcoming version of .net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround could be the following code

```
public static T[,] Copy<T>(T[,] a)
    where T : new()
{
    long n1 = a.GetLongLength(0);
    long n2 = a.GetLongLength(1);
    long offset = 0;
    long length = n1 * n2;
    long maxlength = Int32.MaxValue;
    T[,] b = new T[n1, n2];
    while (length > maxlength)
    {
        System.Array.Copy(a, offset, b, offset, maxlength);
        offset += maxlength;
        length -= maxlength;
    }
    System.Array.Copy(a, offset, b, offset, length);
    return b;
}
```

where the array is copied in blocks of the size `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I've tested with double (size is 8) and it looks like it works even when one array block is about 16 GB.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth but OP is using `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`, so there is no 2 GB limit.

Comment: @wollmich Oh sorry I see, there is no issue with the array size, just there appears to be a contrived limitation in the current `Copy` implementation.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I tried it as well now with `Guid[,] m1 = new Guid[46341, 46341]` and `Guid[,] m2 = Copy(m1)`. This seems to work as well. So the exception message `Arrays larger than 2GB are not supported` isn't right either.

Comment: Arrays have a limitation on the number of elements. [The source seems to protect this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,2b9709b0037280d3). I can't allocate `byte[] b = new byte[int.MaxValue - 1]` even with large objects enabled. Are multi-dimensional arrays considered one array in the runtime or many arrays? That might be masking the per-object storage limitation, but the array element count limitation still exists I think. Looks like `Copy` doesn't cope with multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Multidimensional arrays can have up to 4294967295 elements, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830510/2d-array-with-more-than-655352-elements-array-dimensions-exceeded-supported.

Comment: @Wollmich According to the docs that is the same as a regular array then, which stipulates a max element count of `UInt.MaxValue`. Either way, the copy method seems to constrain it even further, might be worth posting a question / bug to MSFT git pages.