# What is the stack size of a BackgroundWorker DoWork Thread? Is there way to change it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5, backgroundworker, stack-size

I know for a C# main program the stack size 1 MB (32-bit and any) or 4 MB (64-bit), see [Why is stack size in C# exactly 1 MB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28656872/7556646)

What is the default stack size of the `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` thread?

Is there a way to change the stack size of the `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` thread beside creating another thread like the following example:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        // do work with larger stack size
    }, 8192 * 1024);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
```

I'm using a `BackgroundWorker` because I've a `Windows Forms` application where I do some calculations inside the `DoWork` event. I'm doing it this way because I want to report back to the status line of the GUI and I want the possibility that user can cancel the calculations.

I'm getting a stack overflow error because I'm calling Intel MKLs [LAPACKE_dtrtri](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-trtri) which is heavily recursive, see  http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d5c/lapacke__dtrtri_8c_source.html.

The following code shows how I call Intel MKL:

```
public static double[,] InvTriangularMatrix(double[,] a, bool isupper)
{
    int n1 = a.GetLength(0);
    int n2 = a.GetLength(1);
    if (n1 != n2) throw new System.Exception("Matrix must be square");
    double[,] b = Copy(a);
    int matrix_layout = 101; // row-major arrays
    char uplo = isupper ? 'U' : 'L';
    char diag = 'N';
    int lda = Math.Max(1, n1);
    int info = _mkl.LAPACKE_dtrtri(matrix_layout, uplo, diag, n1, b, lda);
    if (info > 0) throw new System.Exception("The " + info + "-th diagonal element of A is zero, A is singular, and the inversion could not be completed");
    if (info < 0) throw new System.Exception("Parameter " + (-info) + " had an illegal value");
    return b;
}
```

and

```
[DllImport(DLLName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
internal static extern int LAPACKE_dtrtri(
    int matrix_layout, char uplo, char diag, lapack_int n, [In, Out] double[,] a, int lda);
```

The `InvTriangularMatrix` is called inside my `DoWork` event. When I'm not setting the stack size I'm getting a stack overflow error inside the `LAPACKE_dtrtri` function.

The size of matrix can be in the order of 1000 x 1000 up to 100000 x 100000. If the matrix is larger than 65535 x 65535 see [2d-Array with more than 65535^2 elements --> Array dimensions exceeded supported range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830510/2d-array-with-more-than-655352-elements-array-dimensions-exceeded-supported).

Comment: BGW uses a threadpool thread, you can't change their stack size.  Do be careful with this kind of workaround, this is in general only needed to fix a problem with recursive code.  If it is a problem while testing then it rarely gets better in production when it needs to process real datasets.

Comment: If you find yourself having to increase stack size, then probably what you should really be doing is converting a recursive method into an iterative one that is implemented using `Stack<T>`.

Comment: If you're creating threads in DoWork, then a BackgroundWorker is not what your want.

Comment: Why are you starting *another background * thread inside BGW's background thread? In any case BGW is obsolete, fully replaced by `Task.Run` and `IProgress<T>`.

Comment: @HansPassant What is the stack size of threadpool thread? I'm using this workaround to call Intel MKLs LAPACKE_dtrtri which is heavily recursive.

Comment: @Wollmich the correct question should be "why should you care"? If you get a stack overflow error it means you have a bug in your recursion code. Arrays aren't allocated on the stack unless you use `stackalloc`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using the `BackgroundWorker` because it has the `ReportProgress` and `Cancel` functionalities. I'm starting another thread because I've to increase the stack size.

Comment: @Wollmich BGW is meant to perform work on the background, not report progress. Again, that's obsolete, replaced by the `IProgress<T>` interface. And you don't need to increase the stack size unless you explicitly try to allocate a big array with `stackalloc`. In any other case, there's a bug in the recursion code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not my recursion code. I'm calling Intel MKLs LAPACKE_dtrtri.

Comment: Post your code then. *How* do you call that method? Using which libraries? Where did you get the error? Don't try to cover it up - the *stack* isn't general-purpose memory, even in C++ and native code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Intel MKL 2019 Update 2, `dllimport`, I'm getting the stack overflow error inside the LAPACKE_dtrtri function.

Comment: It is formally unspecified since it depends on the CLR host, if you target Windows then it is a megabyte in any flavor.  It will never be enough to keep you happy.  Do shop around a bit, matrix inversion isn't rocket science.  Try Math.NET.

Comment: @HansPassant Math.NET is using as well IntelMKL. If you switch to manged it gets to slower for larger problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack size inside a `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` event is the same as for the main thread.

**Prof:**

Set the stack size in a post build event to 8 MB for example:

```
"$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\bin\editbin.exe" /STACK:8388608 "$(TargetPath)"
```

Then ask for the stack size using the following code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern void GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(out uint lowLimit, out uint highLimit);


public static uint GetStackSize()
{
    uint low, high;
    GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(out low, out high);
    return high - low;
}
```

Using `GetStackSize` in the main program and in the `DoWork` event return in both cases 8 MB or whatever you specified using `EDITBIN /STACK`.

Comment: This works only when you start without debugging otherwise it's 1 MB.

Comment: So in debug-mode you will get still for x86 = 1MB and for x64 = 4MB right? atleast for release you get more than .

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2019 you will get your specified stack size even in debug mode. When I wrote the above comment I was still using Visual Studio 2013.