# Powershell: Limit input to a range of numeric values (int or decimal)

Tags: powershell, integer, range, decimal

I have seen this here for different scripting languages, however I have my problem in Powershell and as follows:
I want to limit the input of a numeric value, which can either be a decimal or an integer one, to a specific range.

I tried the following:

```
Do { $value = Read-host "Specify a value between 23.976 and 60"}
while ((23.976..60) -notcontains $value )
```

However it seems that like this it doesn't accept any decimal values at all but only integers. For instance, when I try to enter 29.97 or 29.970 it stays in the loop.

How can I do this right?

Comment: the range operator [the double dot] ONLY allows integers with a max value of 32k. i think the only way to do it will require a `-ge` and a `-le` compound test.

Comment: Yes, I was considering that as well. However, I am having a hard time then building the command line properly:
`Do { $value = Read-host "Specify a value between 23.976 and 60"} 
while ( $value -ge 23.976 ) -and ( $value -lt 60 )`
...doesn't seem to work

Comment: two problems - [1] your ENTIRE `while` test needs to be in one parenthesis pair. you have it broken into two. wrap the whole thing in another paren pair. [2] your `while` test is backwards. as it stands the only accepted answers will be OUTSIDE the range. you want the test to validate IN the range, so the "keep doing it until you get it right" test needs to be "while OUTSIDE of the target range. [*grin*]

Comment: third glitch - your `$value` is text. you likely will need to convert the digit text to a number. i would use `[float]`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Good point about `-ge` and `-le` and generally needing to convert `Read-Host` output to a number for numerical comparison (`[double]` is probably preferable). The fundamental problem here is the attempt to use a `..` range for checking a non-integer number range, but the `while` condition syntax and the logic are otherwise correct (the outside-the-range logic is in the `-notcontains`). As for the `..` operator: The min. / max. _endpoint_ values are `[int]::MinValue` and `[int]::MaxValue`, and, additionally, the resulting array must not have more than `2,146,435,071` _elements_.

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell's [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators?view=powershell-7#range-operator-) - `..` - generates an *array of discrete values*** from the range endpoints, which can have the following types (in a given expression, both endpoints must have the same type):

- `[int]` (`System.Int32`)

  - e.g., `1..3` creates array `1, 2, 3`
  - Note: While the minimum and maximum endpoint values allowed are `[int]::MinValue` and `[int]::MaxValue`, respectively, the resulting array must additionally not have more than `2,146,435,071` elements (2+ billion), which is the max. element count for a single-dimensional `[int]` array in .NET - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2338797/45375) for background information.
- Alternatively, *only in PowerShell [Core, 6+]*: **characters**, which are enumerated between the endpoints by their underlying *code points* ("ASCII values").

  - e.g., `'a'..'c'` creates array `[char] 'a', [char] 'b', [char] 'c'`

Instances of ***numeric* types other than `[int]` are quietly coerced to the latter** - *if* they can fit into the `[int]` range - in which case *half-to-even* midpoint rounding is performed for non-integral types; e.g., implicit `[double]` instances `23.5` and `24.5` are both coerced to `24`.

Because `[int] 23.976` is `24`, your `23.976..60` expression creates array `24, 25, 26, ..., 60` which is *not* your intent.

In short: **You cannot use `..` to describe an uncountable range of non-integers (fractional numbers)**.

Instead, use `-ge` (greater than or equal) and `-le` (less than or equal) to test against the endpoints:

```
-not ($value -ge 23.976 -and $value -le 60)
```

---

Additionally, in order to make the `-ge` and `-le` operations work as intended,  **convert the return value from `Read-Host`, which is always a *string*, to a *number***.
If you were to use `$value` as directly returned by `Read-Host`, you'd get *lexical* (text sort order-based) comparison, not *numeric* comparison.

Therefore, cast the `Read-Host` return value to `[double]`:

```
$value = try { [double] (Read-Host 'Specify a value between 23.976 and 60') }
         catch {}
```

Note: The `try` / `catch` handles the case when the user enters text that cannot be interpreted as a `[double]` representation.

---

To put it all together:

```
do {
  $value = try { [double] (Read-Host 'Specify a value between 23.976 and 60') }
           catch {}
} while (-not ($value -ge 23.976 -and $value -le 60))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, this is how it works ;)

```
Do { $value = Read-host "Specify a value between 23.976 and 60"}
while (( $value -gt 60 ) -or ( $value -lt 23.976 ))
```

Comment: Didn't you see Lee's comment about the `[float]` ?