# C++ program is not giving output involving large array

Tags: c++, arrays, search

Why am I not getting any output from this program?

I tried resolving every issue from YouTube and stack as well but no luck. I tried using vs code extensions and I don't if it has anything to do with JSON configurations.

This is not showing any errors but not showing any output as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int arr[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }

  const int N = 1e6 + 2;
  int idx[N];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    idx[i] = -1;
  }

  int minidx = INT_MAX;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (idx[arr[i]] != -1) {
      minidx = min(minidx, idx[arr[i]]);
    } else {
      idx[arr[i]] = i;
    }
  }

  if (minidx == INT_MAX) {
    cout << "-1" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << minidx + 1 << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Help me find the output of this program.

Comment: What is your input? What is the expected output? `int idx[N];` is probably too large to allocate on the stack. Consider a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: Single-step through the code and examine the variable minidx before cout

Comment: VLAs are not part of C++ and are only provided by individual compiler extension. `int arr[n];` creates a VLA. A couple of other critical areas you won't find on youtube are [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696).

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get no output because your program doesn't run. Instead it [crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes) because of the too large array you're attempting to allocate on the stack. You would know it crashes if you were to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it.

```
const int N = 1e6 + 2;
int idx[N];
```

One way of fixing it, which I don't recommend, is to allocate it on the heap:

```
int *idx = new int[N];
// ... continue as you were
delete[] idx;
```

The necessity of remembering to have to free the heap memory is why I recommend instead you use a `vector`

```
std::vector<int> idx(N);
// ... continue as you were
```

Either way solves the issue of the crash, and your program runs as expected. However, do take note of the advice being given in the comments above about non-standard VLAs and other bad practices.

Comment: Side note: [Why are the terms “automatic” and “dynamic” preferred over the terms “stack” and “heap” in C++ memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782)

Comment: For a small program like this I would also consider it reasonable to allocate `int idx[N];` with static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

Including `bits/stdc++` is invalid, see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102). Instead, include only the headers required by your code, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>      /* for INT_MAX */
#include <algorithm>    /* for std::fill */
```

You may well be triggering your own error if you have a single invalid character (non-digit) in your input. You cannot use any input function correctly unless you check the stream-state following the input and handle `.eof()`, `.fail()` and `.bad()`. See [std::basic_iostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) (under *Member Functions*)

At bare minimum you need something similar to the following that exits the program on bad input. See [std::basic_ios::rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) for the errors corresponding to `.eof()`, `.fail()` and `.bad()` if you want to handle the error more elegantly.

```
    if (!std::cin >> n) {
        std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input 'n'.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!std::cin >> arr[i]) {
            std::cerr << "error invalid integer input 'arr[i]'.\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Your `int arr[n];` creates a C VLA (*Variable Length Array*). The C++ standard does not provide for VLAs and their use is only provided by non-standard compiler extensions.

As mentioned in the comments and other answers `int idx[N];` will attempt to create an array of 1,000,000 integers with *automatic storage duration* that will exceed the stack size on windows (1M) and equal every bite of the total stack size on Linux (4M). You either need to use a container provided by the STL library like `std::vector<int>`, of declare `idx` as a pointer to `int` and allocate storage for `idx` with `new`. (you will then be responsible for freeing the memory with `delete[]`.

If you did want to use allocated storage for both `arr` and `idx`, you can easily do so with:

```
    int *arr = new int[n];    /* VLAs are not part of the C++ standard, 
                               * either allocate for arr, or use std::vector
                               */
    ...
    /* 1e6 will exceed stack stize on windows (1M) and
     * will equal the total stack size on Linux (4M),
     * as with arr, allocate for idx, or use std::vector
     */
    const int N = 1e6 + 2;
    int *idx = new int[N];
```

You will later need to use `delete[]` to free the memory you allocated if not allocating in `main()` (which will be freed on exit).

Instead of looping to fill `idx`, C++ provides [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) to handle the job. This reduces filling `idx` to:

```
    std::fill (idx, idx + N, -1);   /* use std::fill to initialize */
```

There are probably additional issues I've glossed over, which you can find and fix by simply using the proper compiler options. (in addition to checking that `n <= N`)

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. All code you write as you learn C++ should compile without a single warning with full warnings enabled.

A full example that allocates as shown above would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>      /* for INT_MAX */
#include <algorithm>    /* for std::fill */

int main()
{
    int n = 0; 
    
    if (!std::cin >> n) {
        std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input 'n'.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    int *arr = new int[n];    /* VLAs are not part of the C++ standard, 
                               * either allocate for arr, or use std::vector
                               */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!std::cin >> arr[i]) {
            std::cerr << "error invalid integer input 'arr[i]'.\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    /* 1e6 will exceed stack stize on windows (1M) and
     * will equal the total stack size on Linux (4M),
     * as with arr, allocate for idx, or use std::vector
     */
    const int N = 1e6 + 2;
    int *idx = new int[N];
    
    std::fill (idx, idx + N, -1);   /* use std::fill to initialize */

    int minidx = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (idx[arr[i]] != -1) {
            minidx = std::min (minidx, idx[arr[i]]);
        }
        else {
            idx[arr[i]] = i;
        }
    }

    if (minidx == INT_MAX) {
        std::cout << "-1\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << minidx + 1 << '\n';
    }
    
    delete[] arr;
    delete[] idx;
}
```

(**note:** you can `#include <limits>` and use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` instead of using the C `INT_MAX` macro)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Addendum: If you want to force yourself to fix warnings when they pop up with GCC or clang, add `-Werror` to convert warnings into compilation-halting errors.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be a little bit easier to troubleshoot if you prompted for the inputs. I ran your code, and at first it seemed that nothing was being output, but that's because the input needed to be provided first.

Try changing your code to this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

    int main()

{
    int n; 
    cout << "Input a number: ";
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Input a value: ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    const int N = 1e6+2;
    int idx[N];

    for(int i = 0;i < N; i++)
    {
        idx[i] = -1;
    }

    int minidx = INT_MAX;
    for(int i =0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (idx[arr[i]] != -1)
        {
            minidx = min(minidx, idx[arr[i]]);
        }
        else
        {
            idx[arr[i]] = i;
        }
    }

    if(minidx == INT_MAX)
    {
        cout << "The answer is " << "-1" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The answer is " << minidx + 1 << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

You'll notice that based on the first number you enter, you will need to provide the second input that many times. When I ran it this way, I input 5 for the first number, and then 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I got the output of "The answer is -1".

Comment: Also worth noting that `const int N = 1e6+2; int idx[N];` is a stack-killer on a Windows system where the default stack size is 1 megabyte.

Comment: Also worth explaining [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102) and why C++ does not support `int arr[n];` (except by non-standard compiler extension)

Comment: 1e6+2 is only a million and 2 if I'm not mistaken, that should run just fine. I ran it in an online terminal and it executed in less than a couple of seconds

Comment: One million times a minimum of 2 bytes per `int` easily blows off the top of a 1 MB stack without any other variables.

Comment: Still there is no output to this program

Comment: Even after using  your code I am not able to get any output from this

Comment: What are you putting for the inputs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=An%20array%20could%20theoretically%20have,single%20object%20restriction%20in%20the%20.

Comment: C++ and .Net are different things. C++ has no specific limit on the number of elements, though an implementation might. .Net looks like it implies a limit. I don't know my .Net well enough to know if that limit only refers to managed arrays or also applies to unmanaged arrays.

Comment: Regardless, in C++, `idx` is an automatic variable scoped by `main`. It resides in Automatic storage, typically a stack, and the default Windows stack size is 1MB. Other implementations or operating systems may allocate a larger stack. Typical Linux desktop systems default to 8 or 10 MB. So even though the system may allow an array of 2 billion elements, you might run out of storage to hold more elements after a few thousand, a few hundred thousand, a few million, or more, depending on the system.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is very simple.

```
const int N = 1e6 + 2; // in place of this use
const int N = 1e5 + 2; //Use this
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code only answers are less useful.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I was also stuck in this code. But after many trials and research, I get to know that arr size 1e6 is much larger. So I reduced the array size to 1e5.

Answer (score -1):

```
const int N=1e2;
```

change the size of cont int N = 1e2;
or u can apply 1e2 or 1e3 to